# MicroSD Read/Write Speed Factor in ROS / RPi Performance?

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm sure I/O speed is a factor, of course; but I'm trying to determine if the difference in Micro SD card Class (used to designate **write speed** only), say Class 4 vs Class 10, would have a significant impact (such as to be an impede robot operation) on ROS performance. I'm sure ROS does *some* writing, but from what (little) I know, it seems most I/O is conducted over a network. I'm not sure what a ballpark ratio of reading to writing during ROS runtime might be.

Does anyone know if saving a few bucks by buying a Class 4 or Class 6 MicroSD card would be a mistake? Some people say Class 4 is actually faster in applications with a high read-to-write ratio, because the faster write speed of the later Class 10 comes at the cost of slower read speeds. I don't know if that's true or accurate; sounds a bit unlikely to me.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251730/microsd-read/write-speed-factor-in-ros-/-rpi-performance?/) by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2017-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is going to completely depend on your application and how you use ROS. If you're logging bag files onto the uSD card write speed will be a large factor. Read speed can greatly affect your overall system performance, boot up time etc. Many ROS nodes don't have significant disk IO but the only guidance I can give is to estimate your IO load for each node and add it up. But in reality you won't know until you try it for your specific application.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on 2017-01-11**:
@tfoote Thanks! I'm barely past the beginner stage in my ROS experience, so any packages I build for my Wild Thumper-based,  rover-type robot will be quite rudimentary for some time, I'm sure. I may log bag files for debugging. Can I ask: if you were in my shoes, doing nothing more intense with ROS

**Comment by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on 2017-01-11**:
@tfoote than following the tutorials, a book or two; DC motor controller & servo the only actuators; ultrasonic distance sensor or two, would you think an 8GB Class SD card would be adequate? I'll upgrade later; I'm just really eager to get started, but on a very tight student budget. Thanks again!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-01-11**:
Certainly if you have one in hand, start with that. At some point you may find it's limiting you and then you can choose how much to upgrade.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-11**:
@tfoote: what about read performance and the impact on `rospkg` crawling / caching? I'm not sure, but I seem to remember questions about how to disable as much as possible those parts of the infrastructure to reduce node startup time and IO overhead.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-11**:
If you're compiling on your SD card, the read and write speed has a moderate impact on the build time too. I usually spend the extra $ on a Class 10 or Class UHS-I card

**Comment by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on 2017-01-11**:
@gvdhoorn Not sure how much credibility to give this, but a couple posts on the RPi forum and Adafruit said the I/O rate designated by the SD card "Class" denotes **only write** speed, and that write speed is inversely proportional to read speed; e.g. Class 10 card may not read as quickly as Class 6

**Comment by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on 2017-01-11**:
@ahendrix Based on all the comments and replies, it sounds like it's worth it for sure. I'm now beginning to think the reason I had so much trouble getting ROS working properly on my Pi 2 was because of the Class 4 card I was using. Thanks everyone.